# Save array to file

Tags: vb.net

I have a string array that is populated with thousands of entries. I am wanting the quickest way to save this data to disk and to also load it back up.

Currently I am looping through the array and appending this data to a string and then saving this string. This takes a long time.

What is the fastest/most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write

```
 Dim FileName as string=Application.StartupPath & "\myarray.txt"
 IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName,myarray)
```

Read

```
 Dim FileName as string=Application.StartupPath & "\myarray.txt"
 Dim myarray() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

How important is it that the resulting file be human-readable? If it's mostly there to be read later by the program, you should definitely use serialization:

```
public void SaveArray (string[] array)
{
    NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
    using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(_filename))
    {
         serializer.Serialize(file, array);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To summarize the advantages of this method over the other two suggested below, the first being using a StringBuilder to concatenate a big string and then saving it to disk, and the second using WriteAllLines to write the string array to disk:

The first method will completely lose fidelity to the original list of strings, since it will glob them together into one string. Can you separate them later? Are there well-known delimiters between them? Not necessarily. It's more efficient than just calling + between them, but it's not a good way to store them.

The second method is better, since each string will be saved to a different line, and can be read back with ReadAllLines, but you're still on shaky ground here. What happens if any string contains the NewLine character? It will be one string when written, but two different strings when read back. Again, calling WriteAllLines/ReadAllLines relies on newlines being good delimiters, when that's not necessarily the case.

Using a serializer - and it doesn't matter if it's the NetDataContractSerializer, BinaryFormatter or any other - will maintain full fidelity with your original data structure, with only a little bit of overhead.

Comment: The resulting file is not intended to be human-readable. So what is the best way? Serialization, string builder or File.WriteAllLines and .ReadAllLines?

Comment: StringBuilder isn't the right way. It's a better way of concatenating strings together, but that's not answering your original question, it's just giving you a more efficient method of doing things the wrong way. :)

Comment: Serialization is the safest way when you need to recreate the same string array later. Using WriteAllLines, you'd have problems if any of the strings contained NewLine characters - they would be read differently than they were written.

Comment: There are no NewLine characters. It is a listing of files.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to weigh the different options. If you can be sure of no newlines, you can probably do Write/ReadAllLines and save a few lines of code and a few bytes of overhead, but it's not a big deal either way.

Answer (score -1):

Try using StringBuilder

See the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx#Y0) for more

*Why stringbuilder?*

When dealing with large files. It is advisible to use the StringBuilder class rather than the regular string class.
Appending strings together, requires the old string to be copied into a new string.
String Builders are buffers that can change size easily and you can append and delete faster.

Answer (score -1):

You should loop through your data using a string builder which is much faster than ordinary string.

then create a stream writer/ reader (when you want to load the file) from IO library and create the file on your disk.